# Find the index of the first non-zero element in a 2-D array in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to find the index of the first non-zero element in a 2-D array in Simulink, just like I would using the `find(u1, 1)` command in MATLAB.

For example, in MATLAB I would do:

```
u1 = [46.15 61.21; 22.5 45.3; -1 -1; -1 -1; -1 -1];

idx= find(u1<0, 1) % The answer would be: idx = 3
```

Comment: Did you try the `find` block?

Comment: I am not sure I understood well your question. 

You have a 2D vector (a matrix) and you want to find the element index ij of the first element which is non-zero, or less than zero?

How do you want to read the 2D vector?

if you have a matrix like this:

[1 2 3; -1 -3 4]

The first 'less than zero' element would be the element (2,1) which is equal to -1. The first non-zero element would be the (1,1) which is equal to 1.

could you explain yourself better?

Fab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Find` and `MinMax` blocks like so

[image: blocks]

The input should be your logical vector. Any previous computations can be used to gain this.

In the case of your example, you would want to use a `Relational Operator` block to test the `<` condition, and use the output in place of the above input.

The `Find` block will return all indices of non-zero elements. The `MinMax` block (set to take the minimum) can then be used to get the smallest index.

---

You may want to use a `Logical Operator` block, set to OR, to test whether any value is true before you use `Find`. If no value is true, `Find` will return an empty array which will error on entering the `MinMax` block. This can be avoided using `If`/`Else If` logic, as show in the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/if.html) for control flow.